# SKSpriteNode get the value of the angle from 0 to 360 degrees

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I rotate the SKSpriteNode. I need to get the value of the angle in degrees. I use SKNode `zRotation`:

```
print((childNode(withName: "wheel")?.zRotation)! * 180 / CGFloat.pi)
```

The documentation says:

> A positive value indicates a counterclockwise rotation.

But with the rotation of the wheel, angles are printed only up to 180 degrees. Then prints negative angles from -180 to 0! Why? How do I get the angles from 0 to 360 degrees?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My recommendation is that you should not do what you're suggesting. If the rotation is coming out negative, it's because it *is* negative. However, you can do this if you really want to: If the result is negative, add 360 to it. We can readily write a CGFloat extension to take care of that:

```
extension CGFloat {
    var toDegreesNormalized : CGFloat {
        var deg = self * 180 / .pi
        return deg >= 0 ? deg : deg + 360
    }
}
```

Now your code becomes

```
childNode(withName: "wheel")?.zRotation.toDegreesNormalized
```

Comment: Thank you. But 270 degrees and -90 differ in the direction of rotation. If you believe the documentation

Comment: Yes. That is why I said don't change it from being negative. That was the _first_ thing I said. _You_ are the one who wants this value to lie between 0 and 360.